# How to resolve multiple functions that invoke axios get requests within a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, function, promise, axios

Basically I am trying to write a function that will return a list of team scores with the team names next to their score. However because the function which retrieves the team name returns a pending promise I can never see the names in the console.

How do I resolve these promises so that in the next `.then` block of the promise chain I can see the team names either side of the scores as opposed to `[object Promise]`.

[In this picture you can see the full function with the two fetchTeamNames functions stored in the variables][1]

The `fetchFullTimeHeadToHeadScore` function is the parent function:

```js
function fetchFullTimeHeadToHeadScore(homeTeamId, awayTeamId) {
  return axios
    .get(
      `https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/head2head/${homeTeamId}/${awayTeamId}?api_token=${apiKey}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      const homeSide = fetchTeamName(homeTeamId).then((res) => {
        return res;
      });
      const awaySide = fetchTeamName(awayTeamId).then((res) => {
        return res;
      });

      return [homeSide, res.data.data, awaySide];
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data[1].map((obj) => {
        return data[0] + " " + obj.scores.ft_score + " " + data[2];
      });
    })
    .then((scores) => {
      scores.length = 10;
      return scores;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

...which calls the `fetchTeamName` function:

```js
function fetchTeamName(teamId) {
  return axios
    .get(
      `https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/teams/${teamId}?api_token=${apiKey}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data.data.name;
    });
}
```

...which in the console I would expect to enable me to see the names of the teams but currently is only outputting `[object Promise]`:

```
- Expected  - 10
+ Received  + 10

Array [
    -   "1-2",
    -   "3-0",
    -   "1-0",
    -   "4-1",
    -   "1-1",
    -   "1-0",
    -   "0-2",
    -   "1-2",
    -   "0-2",
    -   "2-0",
    +   "[object Promise] 1-2 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 3-0 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 1-0 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 4-1 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 1-1 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 1-0 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 0-2 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 1-2 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 0-2 [object Promise]",
    +   "[object Promise] 2-0 [object Promise]",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `await` to wait for promises instead of using `then`, it might be easier to read (and write).

```js
const res = await axios.get(`xxxx`)
const scores = res.data.data;
```

Word of warning - you didn't explain where you intend to run this code, and what your build process is (if any). `await` isn't always available without using a tool like Babel or esbuild to convert modern JavaScript to JavaScript that's compatible with a wide range of browsers.

However, assuming you're running your code in an environment that supports `async` / `await`, you can also make use of the `Promise.all` function to wait for all 3 promises to complete.

```js
async function fetchFullTimeHeadToHeadScore(homeTeamId, awayTeamId) {
    const homeTeamNamePromise = fetchTeamName(homeTeamId);
    const awayTeamNamePromise = fetchTeamName(awayTeamId);
    const scorePromise = fetchScore(homeTeamId, awayTeamId); // axios.fetch
    const results = await Promise.all([ homeTeamNamePromise, awayTeamNamePromise, scorePromise ]);
    const homeTeamName = results[0];
    const awayTeamName = results[1];
    const matches = results[2];
    return matches.map(match => `${homeTeamName} ${match.scores.ft_score} ${awayTeamName}`);
}
```

If you really need to get this working with promises, this article explains: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Here's the relevant code:

```js
// Make a request for user.json
fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json')
  // Load it as json
  .then(response => response.json())
  // Make a request to GitHub
  .then(user => fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`))
  // Load the response as json
  .then(response => response.json())
  // Show the avatar image (githubUser.avatar_url) for 3 seconds (maybe animate it)
  .then(githubUser => {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
    img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
    document.body.append(img);

    setTimeout(() => img.remove(), 3000); // (*)
  });
```

In your case, it looks like you can slot in a `Promise.all([ homeSide, res.data.data, awaySide ]);` into your code to return the resolved promises for `homeSide` and `awaySide`, and the actual value of `res.data.data` (even though it's not a promise).

```
function fetchFullTimeHeadToHeadScore(homeTeamId, awayTeamId) {
  return axios
    .get(
      `https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/head2head/${homeTeamId}/${awayTeamId}?api_token=${apiKey}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      const homeSide = fetchTeamName(homeTeamId)
      const awaySide = fetchTeamName(awayTeamId)
      return Promise.all([ homeSide, res.data.data, awaySide ]);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data[1].map((obj) => {
        return data[0] + " " + obj.scores.ft_score + " " + data[2];
      });
    })
    .then((scores) => {
      scores.length = 10;
      return scores;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input, this made loads of sense! I have used async/await before but I hadn't realised async resolves promises and had thought it was just an alternate way of structuring promises.

I have implemented the first code block you replied with after some minor editing and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are receiving unhandled promises.

I think you could use Async and await - what this will do is stop your code from compiling when you send your `get` request. Making the code wait until the request is fulfilled, until it continues to compile.

This is a link to an article that could help you get started with it :)

https://dev.to/tutrinh/basic-using-async-and-await-with-axios-ad5

[edit]

This is a rough idea what it could look like - hope this helps somewhat.

```
const fetchTeamName = async(teamId) => {
    try{
        const response = await axios.get(`https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/teams/${teamId}?api_token=${apiKey}`)
        return response.data.data.name
    }  
}
```

Comment: This definitely helped a lot. Thanksyou for you're input and linking me to further documentation, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`fetchTeamName` returns an unresolved `Promise`, whose return value is only accessible within the success function (`.then(onFulfillment, onRejection)`). I think you've recognised this, which is why you've done `fetchTeamName(foo).then((res) => res)`, but the misconception is that you haven't realised that this *also* returns a `Promise`!

There's *no* way to access the result of a `Promise` outside the scope of its instance methods (`.then()`, `.catch()`, etc.).

You could probably do something like

```js
      fetchTeamName(homeTeamId).then((homeSide) => {
        fetchTeamName(awayTeamId)
          .then((awaySide) => {
            return res.data.data.map((obj) => {
              return `${homeSide} ${obj.scores.ft_score} ${awaySide}`;
            });
          })
          .then((scores) => {
            scores.length = 10;
            return scores;
          });
      });
```

but you're probably thinking "hang on, the value of `awaySide` doesn't depend on the value of `homeSide`, so why am I waiting for that API call to complete before I even start the call to get the value of `awaySide`"?

You'd be right to think this! A better solution uses [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
      const homeSidePromise = fetchTeamName(homeTeamId);
      const awaySidePromise = fetchTeamName(awayTeamId);

      Promise.all([homeSidePromise, awaySidePromise])
        .then(([homeSide, awaySide]) => {
          return res.data.data.map((obj) => {
            return `${homeSide} ${obj.scores.ft_score} ${awaySide}`;
          });
        })
        .then((scores) => {
          scores.length = 10;
          return scores;
        });
```

This is better, but it's still hard to read and not much better than the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) that you used to get before `Promise`s were a widely-supported language feature.

A more modern pattern involves using [`async`/`await`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp). This syntax still uses `Promise`s "under the hood", but helps you write code that is much more readable. I'll leave rewriting your code sample with `async`/`await` as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Still developing my understanding of async/await and promises so this was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

as someone has already mentioned; axios returns a promise. Promises are a fundamental part of javascript. You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise . The following for lines are causing the problem (this is not a problem; its just how javascript behaves)

```js
      const homeSide = fetchTeamName(homeTeamId).then((res) => {
        return res;
      });
      const awaySide = fetchTeamName(awayTeamId).then((res) => {
        return res;
      });
```

to overcome this you can wrap the function calls in async. I.e

```
async function fetchFullTimeHeadToHeadScore(...){...}
```

and then use await

```
      const homeSide = await fetchTeamName(homeTeamId)
      const awaySide = await fetchTeamName(awayTeamId)
```

It's better to get an understanding of promises first before using the solution. Good luck